# Early 1980s snap together shop/house scene toy

Tags: set-identification

Hoping someone can help.
I grew up in the 80s and LEGO was my life but one birthday my grandparents bought me a building set which included plastic panels that snap together. When all put together it made a shop and street scene.
From memory there were:
Grey path pieces that interlocked, beige panels for the house, red/brown panels for the roof.
The set also included green stems and little coloured flower pieces which when put together could fit into little holes in the grey path panels.
There were also a few other little pieces that made up the scene.

I’ve researched on google looking at old toy catalogues, I’ve looked on eBay but can’t find anything.

Hopefully someone has an idea as it’s really racking my brain trying to figure out what this early 1980s plastic snap together set was called.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I had the same sets, they formed roads for toy metal cars like Matchbox and Hot Wheels. The product name was [Majo-kit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majo-kit), from a company called Majorette.

[image]

Comment: You legend Phil!!! That’s it!! 
Appreciate it

Comment: Sylakus: One way to show your appreciation would be to click the check box beside the answer, indicating that you've "accepted" it. :)